# Exact solution to system of first-order coupled nonlinear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, initial-value-problems, elementary-functions

I have recently been trying to find an exact solution to the following system of first-order ODEs:

$\begin{cases} \frac{dx}{dt}=y(t)*z(t) \\ \frac{dy}{dt}=x(t)*z(t)    \\ \frac{dz}{dt}=x(t)*y(t)\end{cases}$

Does this system even have, for a given initial condition involving $x,y,z,$ and $t$, a non-trivial solution in terms of elementary functions? I request guidance in finding these non-trivial solutions.

Comment: There's $(0, 0, 0)$ I recommend you ask for guidance looking for solutions or showing there are no non-trivial solutions, rather than asking for the solutions themselves. I'd also recommend you show what you've tried so far.

Comment: It should be clear that $$a xx' + b yy' + c zz' = \frac{1}{2} (a x^{2} + b y^{2} + c z^{2})' = 0 \implies a x^{2} + b y^{2} + c z^{2} = K$$ where $a + b + c = 0$. What does this tell you about the solution set?

Comment: @Matthew Cassell The solution set, a space curve, for a given initial condition must, for some $C\in\mathbb{R}$, lie on the surface $ax^2+by^2+cz^2=C$?

Comment: The solutions are not elementary, they have the form $(x^2,y^2,z^2) = (\wp + \alpha,\wp + \beta, \wp+ \gamma)$ where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are constants and $\wp(t)$ is a [Weierstrass elliptic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_elliptic_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's introduce the auxiliary variable $\tau(t)$ defined by the differential equation
$$
\frac{d\tau}{dt}=yz,\qquad \tau(0)=0. \tag{1}
$$
Then, assuming $yz\neq 0$, we have
$$
\frac{dx}{d\tau}=\frac{\frac{dx}{dt}}{\frac{d\tau}{dt}}=1 \implies x(\tau)=x_0+\tau, \tag{2}
$$
$$
\frac{dy}{d\tau}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{d\tau}{dt}}=\frac{x}{y}=\frac{x_0+\tau}{y} \implies \frac{y^2}{2}=\frac{y_0^2}{2}+x_0\tau+\frac{\tau^2}{2}
$$
$$
\implies y(\tau)=\text{sgn}(y_0)\sqrt{y_0^2+2x_0\tau+\tau^2}, \tag{3}
$$
and, similarly,
$$
\frac{dz}{d\tau}=\frac{\frac{dz}{dt}}{\frac{d\tau}{dt}}=\frac{x}{z}=\frac{x_0+\tau}{z}\implies z(\tau)=\text{sgn}(z_0)\sqrt{z_0^2+2x_0\tau+\tau^2}. \tag{4}
$$
Finally, plugging $(3)$ and $(4)$ into $(1)$ and solving for $t$, we obtain
$$
t(\tau)=\text{sgn}(y_0z_0)\int_0^{\tau}\frac{ds}{\sqrt{(y_0^2+2x_0s+s^2)(z_0^2+2x_0s+s^2)}}. \tag{5}
$$
Equations $(2)$-$(5)$ are the solution, in parametric form, to the given system of ODEs$^{(*)}$.

---

$^{(*)}$ Some of the equations above don't make sense if one or more of $x_0, y_0, z_0$ is zero. These cases must be treated separately.